# How to get a whole object in a schema with mongoose using the 'select' method of 'findOne' instead of explicitly mentioning them all?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My schema looks like the following:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    authentication: {
        password: { type: String, required: true, select: false },
        salt: { type: String, select: false },
        sessionToken: { type: String, select: false },
    },
});
const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

and with the helperfunction

```
const getUserByEmail = (email: string) => UserModel.findOne({ email });
```

In order to get the `password, salt` too in the authentication object, I have to do:

```
const user = await getUserByEmail(email).select('+authentication.salt +authentication.password');
```

if it's just `.select('+authentication')`, the user object doesn't return with the authentication object / `user.authentication returns {}`

How to get a complete object like such?

Comment: What's this `getUserByEmail` API? Is it the `User` model?

Comment: ya it's just UserModel.findOne({ email })

Comment: Since you've added a nested path for `authentication` and marked each field with `select: false`, you'll have to provide each one separately. See [`Queries.prototype.select`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.select()) reference. You can either remove the `select: false` and then always provide a projection to exclude `authentication` for the `getUserByEmail` or whatever API you want, or if you're okay with executing another query to add authentication data, you can add a method on the schema. I'd say go with the former.

Answer (score 1):

Per [`Queries.prototype.select`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.select()) reference it's not possible, however, since you're wrapping the model to create an API like `getUserByEmail`, you can add an optional parameter that would take the authentication path that you might want to use. Since it'd be pretty cumbersome to type it all the time, you can add typings for it in a way that intellisense provides you with all the possible combinations. Something like this -

```ts
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    authentication: {
        password: { type: String, required: true, select: false, },
        salt: { type: String, select: false },
        sessionToken: { type: String, select: false },
    },
});
const UserModel = model('User', UserSchema);

type Paths = `+authentication.${"salt" | "password" | "sessionToken"}`;

type ConcatStringUnion<T extends string, C = T, Separator extends string = " "> = T extends any ? T extends infer U ? Exclude<C, U> extends never ? U & string : `${U & string}${Separator}${ConcatStringUnion<Exclude<C, U> & string>}` : never : never;

type ConcatStringUnion2Pair<T extends string, C = T, Separator extends string = " "> = T extends any ? T extends infer U ? Exclude<C, U> extends never ? [`${U & string}`] : [`${U & string}${Separator}${Exclude<C, U> & string}`, ...ConcatStringUnion2Pair<Exclude<C, U> & string>] : never : never;

type AuthPaths = ConcatStringUnion2Pair<Paths>[number] | ConcatStringUnion<Paths>;


function getUserByEmail(email: string, path?: AuthPaths) {
    let query = UserModel.findOne({ email });
    if (path) {
        query = query.select(path);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Here's a [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAgGRw).